# Geostatistical Analyst toolbar options not accessible

Tags: arcgis-desktop, geostatistical-analyst

I am trying to perform cross-validation for a Kriging interpolation I did on my dataset. For this I wanted to use the *Geostatistical Analyst Wizard* in ArcGIS Desktop.

I have the *Geostatistical Analyst* extension installed and activated in ArcCatalog.

However, when trying to access any options of the *Geostatistical Analyst* toolbar, everything is grayed out and inaccessible.

[image: screen]

I've tried to select a layer (both the original points layer as well as the Kriging-generated raster layer), and I've also tried to close and re-open the program multiple times - still the same story.

Would be glad if someone could help me find out what I'm missing here!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that you have the Geostatistical Analyst extension turned on, as well as the toolbar. If the Geostatistical Analyst toolbar is turned on but the extension is turned off, then all of the options will be greyed out. Customize->Toolbars->Geostatistical Analyst and Customize->Extensions->Geostatistical Analyst. This tool needs to be activated in both locations to operate properly.

Comment: That did it. Both the *Toolbar* as well as the *Extension* needs to be activated **within ArcMap**!